# Nomenclature for signature typing of Typescript member

Tags: typescript

A Typescript class member can be typed as a Function with a specific signature using a variation on lambda syntax, like so:

```
public foo: (p1: string, p2: number) => number;
public bar: (p1: string, p2: number) => void;
```

What is the *name* for this? I want to read the documentation but it's hard to look it up when you don't know the term.

Comment: "Function type expressions" perhaps https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html

Comment: @nate-kumar yes, that's it.  You should write up an answer (you'll get my upvote at least, if you do so and notify me by @-mentioning jcalz in a comment)

Comment: @nate-kumar that is exactly the documentation I seek. Please express this as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: Answer provided, thanks both @jcalz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct term is "Function type expressions" ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html))